# UITextField - white rectangle instead of keyboard

Tags: objective-c, back-button, uinavigationitem, uikeyboard

where is a few UITextField, all UITexfields have same option.

```
self.userPasswordTextField.leftView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 5, 20)];
self.userPasswordTextField.leftViewMode = UITextFieldViewModeAlways;
self.userPasswordTextField.layer.borderColor = [borderColor CGColor];
self.userPasswordTextField.layer.borderWidth = 1.0f;
```

When I click in one UITextfield I see white rectangle instead of keyboard (on simulator).Here is screen:
[image]

Have you ever met with something similar? I tried clear simulator and product, without success.

My second Question is: Why simulator displays still text of back button like "Back", when I have set in Navigation Item - Back Button different text (in some Views it works right, but somewhere no...Also after clean simulator/product).

Answer (score 0):

This is not normal behavior. There must be more to these effects than what you're showing us.

All I can say is: Find this out yourself by starting with some code example that *works*, then change it to what you want to do, until you see the bad effect. Then you know what's causing it better and can ask a specific question that we may be able to answer. Or go hire someone who can look at your code and fix it ;)